# Any way to catch global WM_COMMAND message?

Tags: c#, message, global, wm-command

I'm writing a WPF app that I need use messages such as

- `APPCOMMAND_MEDIA_PLAY_PAUSE`
- `APPCOMMAND_MEDIA_NEXTTRACK`
- etc...

I need catch these message from all running threads (mean global). How can I globally catch these message?